# How to assign labels according to a list in python pandas.Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrame, one is 'recipe', the combination of the ingredients, the other is 'like', which contains the popular combinations.

```
recipe = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['chicken','beef','pork','egg', 'chicken', 'egg', 'beef'],
                       'B': ['sweet', 'hot', 'salty', 'hot', 'sweet', 'salty', 'hot']})
recipe
     A      B
0  chicken  sweet
1     beef    hot
2     pork  salty
3      egg    hot
4  chicken  sweet
5      egg  salty
6     beef    hot 

like = pd.DataFrame({'A':['beef', 'egg'], 'B':['hot', 'salty']})
like
    A      B
0  beef    hot
1   egg  salty
```

How can I add a column 'C' to recipe, if the combination listed in 'like', then I give it value 'yes', otherwise 'no'?

The result I want is

```
recipe
         A      B    C
0  chicken  sweet   no
1     beef    hot  yes
2     pork  salty   no
3      egg    hot   no
4  chicken  sweet   no
5      egg  salty  yes
6     beef    hot  yes
```

The problem is my both dataframes are large. I can not manually choose the items in 'like' and assign the 'yes' label in 'recipe'. Are there any easy ways to do that?

Comment: Could items in `A` be `beef` for example but `salty` in `B` which causes a mismatch?

Comment: @Leb , If `A` is `beef`, `B` is `salty`, then I will assign the label `no`. No mismatch will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) and [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.merge(recipe, like, on=['A','B'], indicator=True, how='left')
print df
         A      B     _merge
0  chicken  sweet  left_only
1     beef    hot       both
2     pork  salty  left_only
3      egg    hot  left_only
4  chicken  sweet  left_only
5      egg  salty       both
6     beef    hot       both

df['C'] = np.where(df['_merge'] == 'both', 'yes', 'no')

print df[['A','B','C']]
         A      B    C
0  chicken  sweet   no
1     beef    hot  yes
2     pork  salty   no
3      egg    hot   no
4  chicken  sweet   no
5      egg  salty  yes
6     beef    hot  yes
```

Faster is use `df['_merge'] == 'both'`:

```
In [460]: %timeit np.where(np.in1d(df['_merge'],'both'), 'yes', 'no')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.22 ms per loop

In [461]: %timeit np.where(df['_merge'] == 'both', 'yes', 'no')
1000 loops, best of 3: 652 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I always think about 'concat' and 'join'. But didn't find the solution. The 'merge' is the answer. :D

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `C` column of `'yes'`s to `like` and then merge `recipe` with `like`. 
The rows that match will have `yes` in the `C` column, the rows without a match will have `NaN`s. You could then use `fillna` to replace the NaNs with `'no'`s:

```
import pandas as pd
recipe = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['chicken','beef','pork','egg', 'chicken', 'egg', 'beef'],
                       'B': ['sweet', 'hot', 'salty', 'hot', 'sweet', 'salty', 'hot']})

like = pd.DataFrame({'A':['beef', 'egg'], 'B':['hot', 'salty']})
like['C'] = 'yes'
result = pd.merge(recipe, like, how='left').fillna('no')
print(result)
```

yields

```
         A      B    C
0  chicken  sweet   no
1     beef    hot  yes
2     pork  salty   no
3      egg    hot   no
4  chicken  sweet   no
5      egg  salty  yes
6     beef    hot  yes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`set_value`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html) by matching both `A` and `B` as such:

```
recipe.set_value(recipe[recipe.A.isin(like.A) & recipe.B.isin(like.B)].index,'C','yes')
recipe.fillna('no')
```

Which will give you:

```
         A      B    C
0  chicken  sweet   no
1     beef    hot  yes
2     pork  salty   no
3      egg    hot  yes
4  chicken  sweet   no
5      egg  salty  yes
6     beef    hot  yes
```

*Note:* These results do not mean my answer is better than other ones or vice versa.

Using `set_value`:

```
%timeit recipe.set_value(recipe[recipe.A.isin(like.A) & recipe.B.isin(like.B)].index,'C','yes'); recipe.fillna('no')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.69 ms per loop
```

Using `merge` and creating new `df`:

```
%timeit df = pd.merge(recipe, like, on=['A','B'], indicator=True, how='left'); df['C'] = np.where(df['_merge'] == 'both', 'yes', 'no')
100 loops, best of 3: 8.42 ms per loop
```

Using `merge` only:

```
%timeit df['C'] = np.where(df['_merge'] == 'both', 'yes', 'no')
1000 loops, best of 3: 187 µs per loop
```

Again, it really depends on what you're timing. Just be cautious of duplicating your data.

Comment: I think, this code is also very clever. But what do you think about the speed compare to `merge`?

Comment: @xirururu read my edit, it all depends on the part that you might be repeating.